# Get folder+filename output

Tags: matlab

In the link: [https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html][1] I can create Interactive List Box App in GUIDE

I tried to add to the end of the  `function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` the line   `fullFileName = [path,name,ext]`  So I can get an output of the path, name and extension (e.g., F:/user/mySoft.m) but it does not work. How can I do it?

```
function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to listbox1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = get(hObject,'String') returns listbox1 contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from listbox1

get(handles.figure1,'SelectionType');
if strcmp(get(handles.figure1,'SelectionType'),'open')
    index_selected = get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
    file_list = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
    filename = file_list{index_selected}
    [path,name,ext] = fileparts(filename)
    fullFileName = [path, name, ext]
end

% ------------------------------------------------------------
% Read the current directory and sort the names
% ------------------------------------------------------------
function load_listbox(dir_path,handles)
cd (dir_path)
dir_struct = dir(dir_path);
[sorted_names,sorted_index] = sortrows({dir_struct.name}');
handles.file_names = sorted_names;
handles.is_dir = [dir_struct.isdir];
handles.sorted_index = sorted_index;
guidata(handles.figure1,handles)
set(handles.listbox1,'String',handles.file_names,...
    'Value',1)
set(handles.text1,'String',pwd)

  [1]: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are having difficulty. Please show your work.

Comment: code section was added. All the code can be found in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a full file address you can use fullfile function.

```
fullfile(path1,path2,...,filename)
```

But I think you want to do this

```
which(filename)
```

The *which* command wil give you the full address of the file when you call a file with the variable *filename*.

Example code:

```
filename="mySoft.m"; %this file does not exist in my computer
address=which(filename);
filename="dosyaBul.m"; %this does exist
address=which(filename)
```

Output:

```
address =

  0×0 empty char array


address =

    'C:\Users\volk\Dropbox\folder\Matlab\dosyaBul.m'
```

Note that you can also use pwd to get active folder on Matlab. In my case:

```
>>pwd

ans =

'C:\Users\volk\Dropbox\folder\Matlab'
```